# Something blocks EventLog registry key under Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-8

I have a problem with Windows 8.

Something blocks any access to any subkeys of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog`. As a result many applications can't be installed.

I can see the list of those subkeys but cannot access them in any way. When I click on a subkey, a message pops up indicating that the key cannot be opened because of an error, `Access denied`.

I also can't edit the `Security Settings` of the keys because of the same message.

I had this problem two days ago and I re-installed my OS. This fixed the problem, but after a day it occurred again. I have the following applications installed: Office 2010, VS2012, WebMatrix, Avast! Antivirus, Google Chrome and Google Picasa.

I've uninstalled Avast, but the keys were still blocked.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same problem has here: [Remove Libraries from Windows 8 Explorer sidebar](https://superuser.com/questions/485342/remove-libraries-from-windows-8-explorer-sidebar)

The below taken from the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/491474/85165) by [FiveO](https://superuser.com/users/161601/fiveo) (which has images).

> 1. Open the "Permission..." on the ShellFolder and open the "Advanced" settings
> 2. Change the Owner to "Administrators"
>
> Now you can set "Full Control" to the Administrators and change the
>   values.